# merge arrays, 0 takes priority over 1

Tags: php, arrays

Basically I need to merge two arrays where the value 0 will take priority over 1.

I can't find any native php function to do this, nor any function on google which surprised me (maybe i have been searching for the wrong things!), and I can't think how to efficiently do it. Any suggestions?

For instance:

```
Array 1                   Array 2
  permission1 => 1            permission1 => 1
  permission2 => 1            permission2 => 1
  permission3 => 0            permission3 => 1
  permission4 => 0            permission4 => 1
                              permission5 => 1
```

The resulting array would be.

```
permission1 => 1
permission2 => 1
permission3 => 0
permission4 => 0
permission5 => 1
```

As you may have guessed this is for a permissions system. Nothing denotes no permission, 0 means never, and 1 means has permission. I thought the best solution might involve adding the two together and seeing if you get 1 or 2, but I can't think how to implement this.

I hope this question is clear, just ask for clarification if not. Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: Something wrong with doing it yourself with a loop to iterate each array and comparing values?

Comment: You could multiply them together if more than one array with the same name exists.

Comment: @MarcB as noted in a comment on a below answer, I thought it might be inefficient on large arrays and thought there may be a better solution. There nearly always is a far better solution to things I think of :)

RetroCoder Oh yea, that would be easier than adding them, whoops!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($array2 as $key => $val) {
   if (!isset($array1[$key])){
        $array1[$key] = $val;
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there is a zero in the second array, this will not work. It should be `(!isset($array1[$key]) ||$array1[key] == 0)`.

Comment: Would this be quite slow with large arrays? Each array is likely to have 100 or so permissions. I thought about something similar to this (but being this concise isn't my strong point!).

Comment: Update: I have this sort of solution working now, but I am going to try @Krycke 's solution posted as a seperate answer and benchmark them both to see which is more efficient.

Comment: I asked if it would be slow, I didn't say it was. And I don't know if a native PHP function would do it differently, my gut just said looping through both arrays in their entirety may be slow when the arrays are large. I was doing a benchmark to see if this is faster or slower than using array_merge and array_intersect_key together. The Benchmark with small arrays, for this solution came back 0.000738417 and for the other solution 0.000733805. So as it stands you are right, the difference is negligible. I have yet to try it with large arrays.

Comment: @Krycke what are you talking about? I'm not doing a truthy conditional.

Comment: @Krycke    Outcome with two arrays each with 70 entries. There were 55 intersects, and 7 0 values. This solution: 0.000157482. array_merge then array_intersect_key solution: 0.000278373. Therefore with this many intersects the simple loop is nearly twice as fast. This best replicates usage in my application, therefore using this as accepted answer. I think the other solution probably would have been marginally quicker with only a few intersects. Thanks both for your help.

Comment: @AlienWebguy Exactly, you don't, and you should. If, let's say, permission 2 in Array2 is a 0, then it will not take priority. That's why you should include that check.

Answer (score 0):

If you first merge the two, and then retrive the ones where they intersect, lastly it retrives only the once with zeroes and foreach loop them to set the zero, you should get the correct answer. This should make the array that you want to loop pretty small.

```
$arr = array_merge( $array1, $array2 );
$intersected = array_intersect_key($array1, $array2);
$intersectWithZeroes = array_keys($intersected, 0);
foreach( $intersectWithZeroes as $key => $value ) {
    $arr[$key] = 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this may be what I am looking for as it only loops through the intersected ones not the whole large array and therefore may be more efficient. I have a solution working using @AlienWebguy 's answer, however I will try and bench mark them both and post the results back here for reference.

Comment: Let me know. This off course depends a lot on how many intersected values there are.

Comment: Indeed, see comment on other answer for benchmark. For my application the other solution is quicker by quite some way. With only a few intersects I think this solution would certainly be faster however.

Comment: @ChrisB added an extra row to just select the values you want to change. This should make it much faster. Making you don't even have to check what value is in the place.